# Accessing Hive from remote server through Python

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, hive

I have installed following necessary packages on the remote server to access Hive through Python.

Python 2.7.6,
Python development tools,
pyhs2,
sasl-0.1.3,
thrift-0.9.1,
PyHive-0.1.0

Here is the Python script to access Hive.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pyhs2 as hive
import getpass
DEFAULT_DB = 'camp'
DEFAULT_SERVER = '10.25.xx.xx'
DEFAULT_PORT = 10000
DEFAULT_DOMAIN = 'xxx.xxxxxx.com'

# Get the username and password
u = raw_input('Enter PAM username: ')
s = getpass.getpass()
# Build the Hive Connection
connection = hive.connect(host=DEFAULT_SERVER, port=DEFAULT_PORT,    authMechanism='LDAP', user=u + '@' + DEFAULT_DOMAIN, password=s)
# Hive query statement
statement = "select * from camp.test"
cur = connection.cursor()

# Runs a Hive query and returns the result as a list of list
cur.execute(statement)
df = cur.fetchall()
```

Here is the output I got:

```
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/__init__.py", line 7, in connect
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/connections.py", line 46, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/cloudera/thrift_sasl.py", line 74, in open
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/cloudera/thrift_sasl.py", line 92, in _recv_sasl_message
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 58, in readAll
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 118, in read
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes
```

I don't see any error in the output after executing the script, however I don't see any query results on the screen. I'm not sure why it's not displaying any query results, Hive server IP, port, user and password are correct. I also verified connectivity between hive server and remote server, no issues with connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
import pyhs2

with pyhs2.connect(host='localhost',
                   port=10000,
                   authMechanism="PLAIN",
                   user='root',
                   password='test',
                   database='default') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        #Show databases
        print cur.getDatabases()

        #Execute query
        cur.execute("select * from table")

        #Return column info from query
        print cur.getSchema()

        #Fetch table results
        for i in cur.fetch():
            print i
```

Comment: Cloudera packge not found error while running this code in python 3

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get access by using the following

```
from pyhive import presto
DEFAULT_DB = 'XXXXX'
DEFAULT_SERVER = 'server.name.blah'
DEFAULT_PORT = 8000

# Username
u = "user"

# Build the Hive Connection
connection = presto.connect(host=DEFAULT_SERVER, port=DEFAULT_PORT, username=u)

# Hive query statement
statement = "select * from public.dudebro limit 5"
cur = connection.cursor()

# Runs a Hive query and returns the result as a list of list
cur.execute(statement)
df = cur.fetchall()
print df
```

Comment: does it try to connect only at the execute statement? because it runs fine till cur.execute. and then gives connection refused err